# Hiding buttons, icons and texts based on resolution using Angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have become decent at responsive html (bootstrap) but now I have to remove elements based on resolution.

Look at browser vs. mobile:

[image]

Based on resolution, some buttons should lose the `md-icon` others lose their text, and a few buttons should be hidden completely.

How can I do that with angular and CSS?

- hide icon but leave text,
- hide text but leave icon,
- hide button completely

Here is some of my code

```
<!--Save Invoice-->
<td style="width:35%; text-align:right; padding-left:4px;">
    <button class="book-button book-text-button book-std-bg" ng-click="vm.invoiceSave()">
        <md-icon class="material-icons book-material" aria-label="Save">save</md-icon>
        SAVE
    </button>
</td>

<!--Pay Invoice-->
<td style="width:30%; text-align:right; padding-left:4px;" ng-if="vm.invoiceForm._id!='new'">
    <button class="book-button book-text-button col-std-cyan" ng-click="vm.invoicePay()">
        <md-icon class="material-icons book-material" aria-label="Save">monetization_on</md-icon>
        PAY
    </button>
</td>

<!--Print Invoice-->
<td style="width:5%; text-align:right; padding-left:4px;">
    <button class="book-button book-text-button col-std-black" ng-click="vm.printInvoice()">
        <md-icon class="material-icons book-material" aria-label="Delete">print</md-icon>
    </button>
</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's builtin classes like

```
.hidden-xs, .hidden-sm, .hidden-md, .hidden-lg
```

Example:

```
<button class="book-button book-text-button book-std-bg" ng-click="vm.invoiceSave()">
    <md-icon class="material-icons book-material hidden-sm" aria-label="Save">save</md-icon>
    <span class="hidden-xs">SAVE</span>
</button>
```

In the above code 'md-icon' will hide in small screens and 'SAVE' text will hide in extra-small screens.

You can refer those classes here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Answer (score 1):

For Hide Icon

Write in Css

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px)
{
     .material-icons  {display:none;}
}
```

For Hide Text

Html Code

```
<td style="width:35%; text-align:right; padding-left:4px;">
    <button class="book-button book-text-button book-std-bg" ng-click="vm.invoiceSave()">
        <md-icon class="material-icons book-material" aria-label="Save">save</md-icon>
        <span class="btntext">SAVE</span>
    </button>
</td>
```

css

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px)
{
         .btntext  {display:none;}
}
```

For Hide Button

In Css

```
 @media screen and (max-width:768px)
    {
             .book-button  {display:none;}
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

**Save Invoice**

```
<td style="width:35%; text-align:right; padding-left:4px;">
    <button class="book-button book-text-button book-std-bg" ng-click="vm.invoiceSave()">
        <md-icon class="material-icons book-material" aria-label="Save">save</md-icon>
        <span class="hide-xs">SAVE</span>
    </button>
</td>
```

**Pay Invoice**

```
<td style="width:30%; text-align:right; padding-left:4px;" ng-if="vm.invoiceForm._id!='new'">
    <button class="book-button book-text-button col-std-cyan" ng-click="vm.invoicePay()">
        <md-icon class="material-icons book-material" aria-label="Save">monetization_on</md-icon>
       <span class="hide-xs"> PAY</span>
    </button>
</td>
```

**Print Invoice**

```
<td style="width:5%; text-align:right; padding-left:4px;">
    <button class="book-button book-text-button col-std-black" ng-click="vm.printInvoice()">
        <md-icon class="material-icons book-material" aria-label="Delete"><span class="hide-xs">print</span></md-icon>
    </button>
</td>
```

Comment: answer isnt clear and doesn't provide a code example or useful links